# How to convert relational tables to one single table using spring boot and dynamodb

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, relational

I am some how confused and can't think how this can be done using the dynamodb

if we have for example
Student
Course
Teacher

each student is subscribed to many courses
each teacher can teach many courses
each course can has many students

the Access patterns I want is
1- get student by id
2- get teacher by id
3- get course by id
4- get student by email or by name
5- get teacher by email or by name
6- get course by name

can any one help me How I can make this in java spring boot
I can write entity for each one but I want them to be one single table and am confused how this can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but I gonna structure like this

```js
Students
{
 uid: String,
 name: String,
 courses: <Courses<uid>>[],
}

Teachers
{
 uid: String,
 name: String,
 courses: <Courses<uid>>[],
}

Courses
{
 uid: String,
 name: String,
}
```

```js
// get item by uid
var params = {
    TableName: "tableName",
    Key:{
        "uid": "Youruid",
    }
};

docClient.get(params);

// get item by name
var params = {
    TableName: "tableName",
    Key:{
        "name": "SomeName",
    }
};

docClient.get(params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply can u say how can I write that in the form of terraform file ? and an model in spring boot as that will be reflected to 3 tables I want only one single table